# lost focus and got focus events of a text box

Tags: c#

1.How to give both lostfocus event and gotfocus event for a textbox at the same time?
2.That is, i have to append % to a text box, so i will use lost focus event.
3.But whenever the user again goes to d text box i need to call got focus event.
4.So is this possible to call both the events of a text box at the same time??

this is for lostfocus event:

```
protected void lostfocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtMarks.Text != "")     
  {
    txtMarks.Text += "%";          
    ddlGrade.Focus();
  }
else
 {
txtMarks.Text = "";          
    ddlGrade.Focus();
 }
}
```

this is for gotfocus event:

```
 protected void lostfocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtMarks.Text.contains("%"))     
      {
        txtMarks.Text = "";          
        ddlGrade.Focus();
      }
    }
```

Comment: well messy code, I think you want something like this: You want the textBox should show a value with % appended, but if it is in edit mode, the % should be removed.

Comment: do you want to put this logic or functionality inside a single function ? if not then what do you mean by call both the functions at the same time

Comment: why do you want to call both event at same time?

Comment: i got the desired output mr.king... i just wanna know whether v can call both the events at the same time for a single text box . so this might be useful for me in some other scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append "%" on lost focus and clear the value when you got focus, maybe you should consider adding a separate label on the right of the textbox with the content "%". In this way the user will know that this is a percentage textbox. What you want to do does not look very nice.

Instead of

```
if (txtMarks.Text != "")
```

use this

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMarks.Text))
```